Register for course that starts today
How can I register for a course that starts today: Working with Neurodivergent Patrons and Colleagues, when the online link to register is not available?

Could you please add more context to your question? How is this related to CiviCRM?

I assume they are trying to sign up for this event - https://infopeople.org/civicrm/event/info?id=1124&reset=1 - but that registrations were closed off when the event started. Suggestion is to contact the organisers via https://infopeople.org/about/contacts
